# Sending a POST request with retry using HTTPClient

Tags: c#

So I've been searching like a mad man after a way to solve this issue, but I can't seem to find an answer.

So, I need to send a `POST` request with `HTTPClient` in C# to a server, and if the server isn't running it will keep sending the request until it connects (or dies after a nr of attempts). But I always get the exception `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException`, which wouldn't be a problem if I just could store it (or something) and try again.

I found a couple of ways that people tried to do this, and I've tried them all. Creating a `for-loop` that loops and catches the exception that the program throws, adds to the counter and tries again. Creating a `while-loop` that loops until the `HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode == true`. I've even gone to such lengts as restarting the program if it can't connect (yeah, I'm that desperate).

So, I had to see if anyone of you guys might have a solution to this problem, or if you maybe had a better way to solve this problem. 
Here is the code im running, thanks for your help!
**EDIT:** Just to add some clarity, the exception is thrown at the "rep"-variable, and the code never runs further than to that variable. And I've tried to make the HTTPResponseMessage variable just a "var" and await the Postasync method to.

```
HttpResponseMessage rep = new HttpResponseMessage();

try
{
    rep = client.PostAsync("https://localhost:9999/", content).Result;
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}


Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ContinueTrasmission(client, c1.name, c1.state));
```

Comment: Why should the counter be a problem?

Comment: Where is this exception thrown? The `catch` will catch that exception if it's thrown inside the `try`. It's really not clear what the question is here?

Comment: Ah sry, the exception is thrown at the "rep" responseMessage, the compiler never steps further than the "rep"-variable.

Comment: *Don't* use `.Result` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`. The first blocks and negates any benefit you gained by using HttpClient. Use Task.Run if you want to run anything in the background.

Comment: BTW what *did* you try? Where is the loop you mentioned? Creating a retry loop isn't that difficult

Answer (score 1):

You have to look for retry libraries, [for example Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)

```
var policy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(_retryCount, retryAttempt => 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));

policy.Execute(() => DoSomething());
```

Comment: That doesn't show how to retry a POST call. It's the actual details of `DoSomething` that matter, not how you call it. For example you can't reuse the same HttpRequestMessage

Comment: I can't ask author in comments (not enough rep), but I think we are missing something. At least description of an error.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:

```
bool success = false;

while (!success)
{
    var rep = new HttpResponseMessage();

    try
    {
        rep = client.PostAsync("https://localhost:9999/", content).Result;

        //No exception here. Check your condition and set success = true if satisfied.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Log your exception if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but as soon as the exception i thrown from the "rep"-variable, the program just halts, it never even enters the catchblock.

Comment: @RealJohnsson where is the rest of the code? Did you try *debugging*? The program doesn't halt by itself. What type of application are you building. The very call to `.Result` is a huge issue itself.

Comment: Agree with you @PanagiotisKanavos. Please show the rest of your code.